# awk "if" statement

Tags: awk

I have a file

```
foo
--
bar
```

I only want the lines above the separator. I've struggled with this for too long and tried a number of variants. My one liner is:

```
echo -e "foo\n-- \nbar" | gawk -v x=0 -- '/^--\ / { x++ } ; IF (x==0) {print} '
```

This should print only "foo" but I get the whole file output. If I change to print x I get

```
0
1
1
```

I can't seem to make make awk conditionally print a line based on the value of x. I know I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
echo -e "foo\n-- \nbar" | awk '/^--/{exit}1'
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

- `/^--/` is a regex to match the string at the beginning of the current line
- `{}` part is executed if the condition is *true* (the previous regex)
- `1` is like `{print}` : by default, `awk` print on STDOUT if a condition is *true*. While `1` is *true* for awk, it print the current line.

Decomposition of the command :

```
echo -e "foo\n-- \nbar" | awk '
    {
        if (/^--/) {
            exit
        }
        else {
            print
        }
    }
'
```

Alternative decomposition:

```
echo -e "foo\n-- \nbar" |
awk '(/^--/) { exit }
             { print }'
```

This emphasizes that there are two pattern-action rules; one with an explicit pattern and an exit action; the other with implicit pattern and print action.

Comment: cryptic is good for later but I need to understand it first. I like the exit but what is that 1 for?

Answer (score 2):

If you like `sed` better:

```
sed -n '/^--$/q;p' file.txt
```

Explanation: `sed` reads the file line by line. If sed finds the pattern `^--$` (i.e., a line that contains exactly `--`) it quits (that's the `q` command), otherwise, `sed` prints out the content of that line (with the `p` command). Note that `sed` was launched with the `-n` option, i.e., doesn't output anything unless explicitly told to with the `p` command. Since `sed` quits when the separator `--` is found (i.e., before the `p` command), this separator will not be printed.

The good thing about `sed` is that it's faster than `awk` for this task.

**Edit.** As glenn jackman points out in a comment, with GNU sed, you can use:

```
sed '/^--$/Q' file.txt
```

(I wasn't on a computer that had a `sed` with the `Q` command when I answered). Thanks glenn.

Comment: This does the same thing: '`sed '/^--$/Q'` -- Q exits without printing. Requires GNU sed.

Comment: @glennjackman Ah you're right! I didn't have the same version of `sed` as the one I have here, and didn't find the `Q` command in the man page... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your original script was on the right lines but too complex:

```
echo -e "foo\n-- \nbar" | gawk '/^--\ / { x++ } { if (x==0) print}'
```

Variables are automatically created and zeroed by `awk` (so you don't need `-v x=0` etc).  The 'spot the double dash' code was fine.  The semi-colon is unnecessary (at best).   The `IF (x == 0) {print}` is plain weird.  The `awk` on Mac OS X 10.7.5 accepts it, but I'm not sure what it was doing.  The replacement action is for every line, and tests whether `x` is zero before printing.

Personally, I'd probably use `sed` for this:

```
echo -e "foo\n-- \nbar" | sed '/^--/q'
```

Fixing my `sed` command as [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13662135/15168):

```
echo -e "foo\n-- \nbar" | sed -n '/^--/q;p'
```

You can mimic that in `awk` with the command shown by [sputnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465183/sputnick) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13661945/15168).

```
echo -e "foo\n-- \nbar" | awk '/^--/ {exit} 1'
```

The 1 matches every line (it is always true) and triggers the default action, which is 'print $0'.  You could also write:

```
echo -e "foo\n-- \nbar" | awk '/^--/ {exit} {print}'
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: oh, yes...I suppose it does...your's doesn't...copy, crib, cheat...

Answer (score 1):

In GNU awk you could just set the record separator to be a line that only contains "--" and then just print the first record:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\n--\n' 'NR==1' file
foo
```

or if performance is a concern:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\n--\n' 'NR==1{print;exit}' file
foo
```

that way you can enhance the script later to print any other record you might want:

```
$ cat file
the
quick
--
brown
fox
--
jumped
$
$ gawk -v RS='\n--\n' 'NR==1' file
the
quick
$ gawk -v RS='\n--\n' 'NR==2' file
brown
fox
$ gawk -v RS='\n--\n' 'NR==3' file
jumped
```